# Why won't my Javascript randomColors function produce a random background when clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm teaching myself JavaScript and I'm trying to make a random background color appear when a button is clicked. Below you can find my code:

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Day 4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body id="background">
<div class="row">
<div class="columns small-12">
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://carter3689.tumblr.com/">Blog</a></li>

</ul>   

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-12">
        <div class="container center">

        <button id="button"class="button center" onclick="randomColors">Click Here for Color of the Day</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


</div>
<script src="js/random-color.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS Code:

```
.background{
    background-color: #ECECEA;
}
.text-padding{
    padding: 50px;
}
input{
    width:250px !important; 
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.inline{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.container{
    margin-left: 500px;
}
```

And lastly, my JavaScript Code. This is where I'm having most of my trouble to be honest.

```
function randomcolor(){
    document.getElementById('background').style.color =randomColors();
}

function randomColors(){
    return '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    console.log("I'm working now")

}
```

Any help you can provide would be extremely helpful as this is all a learning experience for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.style.backgroundColor = randomColors();`

Comment: `onclick="randomColor"`

Comment: DO you realize your console.log is after the return so it would never execute?

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip on the console.log. I wasn't sure where I needed to place it to test the function. I appreciate that greatly, everything is a learning experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened is when your html loads, the onclick handler is undefined because your script hasn't been loaded as yet.. .hence you will get an  an error in your console.log stating that your function is undefined. Move script tag above your onclick handler.

**Snippet using .onclick**

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick=randomcolor;
function randomcolor(){
    document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundColor =randomColors();
}

function randomColors(){
var result='#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
console.log(result);
    return result;
    
}
```

```css
    .background{
    background-color: #ECECEA;
}
.text-padding{
    padding: 50px;
}
input{
    width:250px !important; 
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.inline{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.container{
    margin-left: 500px;
}
```

```html
    <title>Day 4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<body id="background">
<div class="row">
<div class="columns small-12">
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://carter3689.tumblr.com/">Blog</a></li>

</ul>   

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-12">
        <div class="container center">

        <button id="button"class="button center">Click Here for Color of the Day</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


</div>



</html>
```

**Snippet using `addEventListener`**

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',randomcolor,false)
function randomcolor(){
    document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundColor =randomColors();
}

function randomColors(){
var result='#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
console.log(result);
    return result;
    
}
```

```css
    .background{
    background-color: #ECECEA;
}
.text-padding{
    padding: 50px;
}
input{
    width:250px !important; 
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.inline{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.container{
    margin-left: 500px;
}
```

```html
    <title>Day 4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<body id="background">
<div class="row">
<div class="columns small-12">
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://carter3689.tumblr.com/">Blog</a></li>

</ul>   

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-12">
        <div class="container center">

        <button id="button"class="button center">Click Here for Color of the Day</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


</div>



</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like its basically already been answered by others, but there is nothing wrong with repetition.

1. You are calling `randomColors()` instead of `randomcolor()`.
2. You really shouldn't be using getElementById on the body tag. You can just use document.body to get the body.
3. You need to use `style.background` or `style.backgroundColor` to get the background color instead of text color.
4. You should be including your js scripts in `<head>` instead of near the bottom of your html document to ensure they are loaded before functions from them are called.

Comment: In this case including the script at the  bottom works just as well since there are no script block that call anything before the script (note: onclick only gets called after the user clicks - which is long after the bottom of the page have loaded). Indeed, Google and a lot of other page optimisation guides recommend you put scripts at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking too, but he said he was new to javascript. Its probably going to be more helpful for him that his code is more likely to work than it being better optimized.

Comment: Hey Guys, the script being placed at the bottom of the page is actually the way I learned it initially. I didn't know however, that certain calls would block the loading of certain scripts. That is a nugget of information that I will keep handy as I progress.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using the wrong function in your callback. Use `onclick='randomcolor()'`. Make sure your JS functions are defined in the `<head>` of the document. Finally, `document.getElementById('background').style.color` is the text color, not the background color. Use `document.getElementById('background').style.background = randomColors();`